# How to get start with flex?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flex, jakarta-ee

I know this question may be asked 100 times but I haven't got any answer which was fullfiled my requirement. Even I searched on google but I failed to understand. Here is my question. I have developed an JAVA Webapp on `Spring 3.0 + Hibernate 3.0 + JBoss AS 7.1 + MySQL`. Now for rich UI I want to use flex as front end instead of using jsp pages. So from where to start? `Is there any plugin for eclipse so that I can desgin UI and mxml file will be generated?(like we use to do for swing).` `Is flex builder 3 an paid app?`  I read somewhere that for flex builder adobe provide 60 days trial version but when I am trying to download nothing is coming up on adobe site. I will be very helpful if somebody helps me, guiding thourgh this very first painful steps.

Comment: you did not search very hard did you.  http://flex.apache.org/

Comment: thanx @user2310289 but I was looking for IDE and moreover I read that abode donated this to apache so I was confused which thing I should go with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe your question has been fully answered so I will give it a try.

As far as I can tell you are really asking 4 questions:

1. Where to begin?
2. Is there a plugin for eclipse?
3. Is Flex 3 a paid app?
4. Where to download Flex 3?

First let me start off by clarifying a few things. Flex used to be both a framework and an IDE to program in said framework, both produced by Adobe. So we had the Adobe Flex framework and the Eclipse based Adobe Flex Builder IDE. The Flex framework was donated to Apache and thus becoming Apache Flex. The Flex Builder application was re-branded to Flash Builder so it is now Adobe Flash Builder. And of course Flex applications are compiled to code that runs on the Flash Player.

Now that we got that out of the way, I will answer you questions in reverse order.

4 - You can download the latest version of the Apache Flex SDK at their website (http://flex.apache.org/). You can download the latest version of Flash Builder from the Adobe site. However the latest version of Flash Builder (4.7) has design view removed from it so to use drag and drop design view you will have to download version 4.6 for which you can find links at this Adobe forum post:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4908407

Adobe software will typically give you a 30 day trial. You mention Flex Builder 3 (Flash Builder was known as Flex Builder a the time of this release) in your questions. That version is no longer available through legitimate means. I would also not recommend using it since it is really outdated and most likely does not support the latest versions of the Flex framework.

3 - Yes, Flex Builder 3 was a paid app and Flash Builder 4.6 is a paid app. Note that you can purchase Flash Builder 4.7 and get a downgrade key from adobe to also use 4.6 at the same time. The reason you would want to use 4.7 is to take advantage of the latest Flex related mobile development.

2 - There was a plugin for eclipse for Flex Builder 3, you had the option to install it as a plugin, which means that you still had to pay for it. I don't recall if Flash Builder 4.x can be installed as a plugin but I would recommend just using the full Flash Builder IDE, specially if you are new to Flex programming.

1 - I think you are on the right track by getting the environment down first. Next I would watch the Flex in a Week tutorials by Adobe.

I would also think carefully about how to communicate between your application and the server. Since your application is a Spring based application you may want to look at the Spring BlazeDs integration project. However I would lean towards producing JSON or XML from the back end to consume on your Flex application via AJAX like communication. This way, it will make it easier to switch the front end technology if you ever need it.

I hope this answers all you questions, cheers.

Comment: Thanx sir, you clarified my all doubts, I am thinking of usindg Cairngorm framework.

Answer (score 1):

If I only would know what all these you mentioned are? (except MySQL) maybe then I could advise about this and that, but I just started myself to make the change over from FLEX 3.5 to FLEX 4.6 as my Applications I wrote over the last few years are in need of been updated to greener pastures!
I would not start with say FLEX 3.5 as that would not get you anywhere any longer yet if you would have say FLEX 4.5 or 4.6 yo still could use or develop in 3.5 as well that is just the great thing about starting with say 4.5, 4.6 or current 4.7 APACHE.
All the ADOBE developing software like FLEX is free for a 30 day trial! and there is another item you ask for about generating well you could write the Applications in Mxml, in AS3 or in both - but again that is a choice you make once you know more about FLEX .... and more about the Mxml and the AS3.
A lot of questions believe me with very basic answers but which could be more in detail if once know about what your App is all about? ........... regards aktell